# In C# how does referencing a class work when you only provide the last "word" in the namespace?

Tags: c#

```
using A.B;
using X.Y;

public void Get(B.C c) {

}
```

How does this mechanism to import work in C#? (the B.C on the method). Where can I find some docs on it?

When I try other packages to import in this way it doesn't work...

In rider if I go "B." I get a bunch of code insight options... (A.B is my code) but if I type "Y." I don't get any options (X.Y) is library code. It seems to be that the code insight works in namespaces that have my code in them.

Updated question to use using instead of import.

Comment: `import` isn't a keyword in C#; did you mean `using`?

Comment: What namespace is *this* code inside, as you write it. Is `A` part of it?

Comment: this question is more related to how does **Intellisense** work rather than C# itself

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever how is the namespace relevant? Do you get "relative" usings?

Comment: @Hoshani the code that is produced still has to be valid C#, so I disagree.

Comment: If X.Y "is [compiled] library code" then Visual Studio logically cannot look inside this class and cannot have autocomplete. You can help Visual Studio by placing the XML file of this library to the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Namespace and type names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#namespace-and-type-names):

> a *namespace_or_type_name* has one of four forms:
>
> - `I`
> - `I<A1, ..., Ak>`
> - `N.I`
> - `N.I<A1, ..., Ak>`

And then<sup>1</sup>:

> for each namespace N, starting with the namespace in which the *namespace_or_type_name* occurs, continuing with each enclosing namespace (if any), and ending with the global namespace, the following steps are evaluated until an entity is located:

> ...

> Otherwise, if `N` contains an accessible type having name `I`
> ...
> Otherwise, the *namespace_or_type_name* refers to the type constructed with the given type arguments.

So, if your code is in the namespace `A.Q.R`, and there's no `B` namespace in `R` nor `Q`, then eventually it will resolve to `A.B.C`. (Note, the `using A.B;` isn't relevant here)

---

<sup>1</sup>I'm trying to take out a lot of the caveats here which are irrelevant to this case but really, you do need to look at the full specification to get all of the details